# Convert epoch js with false time in device

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, meteor

My local sensor-device is confiugured with localtime:"11.01.1970 
09:35:39","utctimestamp":894939.
I can not set a ntp-client in the device. 
I receive timestamp values in ms unit.

How can i convert it to the actual time with Javascript ?

```
new Date(ms) gives 1970 year values
```

And how i convert timestamps like 2015-07-09 00:00:00 to ms epoch values ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a javascript plugin called moment.js
They have a very nicely maintained documentation.
Basically you can get the current time in javascript like:

```js
new Date().getTime();
```

And this value can be converted to different formats using moment.js as per their documentation.

Comment: the problem is my sensor has not the actual timestamp it gives 1970 values. and i want it to adapt to the actual 2016 date